# How to find programmatically location of a dynamic library file?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos

I want to find the path in the system (if any) of a specific library
right now I have a built ins path:

```
dllNameFrodo = "/usr/local/frodo/lib/libfrodo.dylib";
```

but of course is ugly and not portable.

Any ideas ?

Comment: They could be anywhere. Each of these systems has some loose convention, but there's no way to locate them in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to load a hardcoded path, either package the library locally with your application so you know where it's installed, or better yet, just let the runtime loader find and load it automatically. This way the user can fiddle with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD to pick which version to load.

Answer (score 1):

It's like searching for any kind of file - given it's name or extension and some hints of where to start searching-, so if what you want is to search in a portable way you have 2 solutions :

1. use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm)
2. build some search functions and implement once per platform using platform-specific functions. Hint : that's what boost::filesystem is -with sugar on top- but if you don't want or can't use boost, then it's the only "portable" alternative.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and family.

This is pretty specialized requirement - portable implementation might be hard to find and in any case is going to use platform-specific APIs underneath if it's going to be optimal on all.